# Recursive function allocating pointer twice?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

This is an indirect homework question, this question isn't on the assignment, but im curious nontheless.
We are given the following function:

```
int silly(int n, int *p)
{
    int val, val2;
    if (n > 0)
        val2 = silly(n << 1, &val);
    else
        val = val2 = 0;
    *p = val + val2 + n;
    return val + val2;
}
```

And told it compiles to the following assembly code:

```
silly:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    subl $20,%esp
    pushl %ebx
    movl 8(%ebp),%ebx
    testl %ebx,%ebx
    jle .L3
    addl $-8,%esp
    leal -4(%ebp),%eax
    pushl %eax
    leal (%ebx,%ebx),%eax
    pushl %eax
    call silly
    jmp .L4
    .p2align 4,,7
.L3:
    xorl %eax,%eax
    movl %eax,-4(%ebp)
.L4:
    movl -4(%ebp),%edx
    addl %eax,%edx
    movl 12(%ebp),%eax
    addl %edx,%ebx
    movl %ebx,(%eax)
    movl -24(%ebp),%ebx
    movl %edx,%eax
    movl %ebp,%esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

I noticed after compiling this that at `-8(ebp)`, p seems to also be stored. Now, p is also stored at `12(ebp)`. Why is this? I cannot find any explicit code mapping p to `-8(ebp)`.

Edit: I should clarify the question, I compiled this code here: https://gist.github.com/jamiees2/dceaf1ba90b84ebbac0e with `gcc -Wall -m32 test2.c test2.s -o bla` and then `gdb bla`. I set a breakpoint at silly `b silly` and then ran `x/x *((int*)($ebp+12))` and `/x *((int*)($ebp-8))` respectively, which gave the same output. I am wondering why this is. Is it just garbage on the stack? Or is there some hidden functionality there?

Comment: What makes you think it's stored at `-8(%ebp)`?

Comment: never see `-8(%ebp)` shown.

Comment: Like i said, im confused, because i don't see it at all. But when i compiled the code, meaning i put the assembly code in a .s file and linked it against a .c file with `gcc -m32`, then debugged it with gdb, the output lead me to believe that. After setting a breakpoint within `silly`, then `x/x *((int*)($ebp+12))` and `x/x *((int*)($ebp-8))` gave me the same thing.

Comment: I uploaded my code here: https://gist.github.com/jamiees2/dceaf1ba90b84ebbac0e
Compile with `gcc -Wall -m32 test2.c test2.s`

Comment: Perhaps you should post your entire `gdb` session transcript.

Comment: That is true, i added it to the gist.

Answer (score 0):

The incoming argument `n` is stored at `8(%ebp)`.  The incoming argument `p` is stored at `12(%ebp)`.  You have misunderstood the assembler code.

`val` is stored at `-4(%ebp)`.  The saved value of `%ebx` is stored at `-24(%ebp)`.  Note that `%ebx` is preserved across calls.  This is why `silly` saves and restores it, and why it can rely on `%ebx` continuing to contain the value of `n` across the recursive call to `silly`.

Comment: Hmm, yes, i figured that much, but when i ran the code through gdb, `x/x *((int*)($ebp+12))` and `x/x *((int*)($ebp-8))` gave the same thing. The actual assignment was effectively to figure out what you just said, but i noticed this anomaly. I put the assembly code in a .s file and compiled it with `gcc -m32`, if that helps.